# redgate oracle 12c compare shows noneditionable

Tags: database, oracle, redgate

Why does Redgate compare for Oracle show NONEDITIONABLE for objects?

We have installed Oracle 12C locally on a windows machine to dry run database scripts before running them on the main Oracle 12C database on a Unix machine.

After running the scripts on the local version we run Redgate Schema compare and find that some of the Views and Triggers don't match. Upon further review the only difference between the two is the word "NONEDITIONABLE". This is not part of the our script and we are unsure how this was added to the local version of the object.

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE NONEDITIONABLE

When researching EDITIONING we thought that maybe it was because the local Oracle install wasn't a portable database (PDB), so we changed our install, and confirmed that the EDITIONS_ENABLE was 'Y' for the user.

We are restoring a dump of the main to our local, and it appears to only be the objects that existed previously. Any new objects do not experience this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was never able to find a good solution in the local 12C version install. I finally used the restored 12C version to create by own backup, which I downgraded to the 11.2 version for Oracle Express. Once I restored the downgraded version the comparison and ran the scripts I no longer experienced an issue with the compare.